# react-router-dom route component requires page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

When calling history.push('/packages') the url is updated but the component will not mount (render) unless the page is reloaded. If I call createHistory({forceRefresh: true}) or manually reload the page the UI is rendered correctly. How can I configure react-router-dom to load the component without explicitly reloading the page or using forceRefresh?

***index.jsx***

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import store from './store'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

***App.jsx***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Navbar, PageHeader, Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import LoginFormContainer from './components/Login/LoginFormContainer'
import PackageContainer from './components/Package/PackageContainer'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Navbar>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand><h3>Mythos</h3></Navbar.Brand>
          </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
        <Row className="content">
          <Col xs={12} md={12}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/packages' render={() => <PackageContainer />} />
              <Route exact path='/' render={() => <LoginFormContainer />} />
            </Switch>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

***loginActions.jsx***

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import LoginApi from '../api/loginApi'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory()

export function loginUser(user) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return LoginApi.login(user).then(creds => {
      dispatch(loginUserSuccess(creds));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  }
}

export function loginUserSuccess(creds) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('credentials', JSON.stringify(creds.data))
  history.push('/packages')
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    state: creds.data
  }
}
```

***PackageContainer.jsx***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {loadPackages} from '../../actions/packageActions'
import PackageList from './PackageList'
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes'
import {Map,fromJS,List} from 'immutable'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

class PackageContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadPackages());
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12">
        {this.props.results ?
        <PackageList results={this.props.results} /> :
        <h3>No Packages Available</h3>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PackageContainer.propTypes = {
  results: ImmutablePropTypes.list.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    results: !state.getIn(['packages','packages','results']) ? List() : state.getIn(['packages','packages','results'])
  };
}

PackageContainer = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(PackageContainer))

export default PackageContainer
```

Comment: Try `<Route path='/packages' render={PackageContainer} />` and remove `withRouter` from your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that issue that you are create new instance of `history` object but `BrowserRouter` doesn't know about the changes which happens inside of it.

So, you should create history object and export it in the `index.jsx` and use `Router` instead of `BrowserRouter` and pass as `history` property, so then you can just import it whenever you need.

For example:

**index.jsx**

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
...

export const history = createHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Then, in `loginActions` you just import `history` and use `.push` method as before.

**loginActions.jsx**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import LoginApi from '../api/loginApi'
import { history } from './index'

export function loginUser(user) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return LoginApi.login(user).then(creds => {
      dispatch(loginUserSuccess(creds));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  }
}

export function loginUserSuccess(creds) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('credentials', JSON.stringify(creds.data))
  history.push('/packages')
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    state: creds.data
  }
}
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: This works, thanks! So, do I need to use Router instead of BrowserRouter because I'm using redux?

Comment: @neridaj Not quite. Actually, `BrowserRouter` ignores the history prop, so we should use custom history and pass it to `Router` instead. It's not connected with `Redux` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In the App.jsx

```
<Switch>
     <Route path='/packages' render={(props) => <PackageContainer {...props}/>} />
     <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <LoginFormContainer {...props}/>} />
 </Switch>
```

Now both **PackageContainer** and **LoginFormContainer** have access to ***history*** object